# Show function not working with :before

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this click function to show a :before and for some reason it wont show it ? Here is my code thank you!
Also the .cart-toggle:before class is display:none; so it can show.

```
$( ".cart-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $( ".cart-toggle:before" ).show( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

jQuery (and javascript in general) does not support CSS pseudo classes as they are not part of the DOM.

The workaround depends on what you're trying to do, but animating a pseudo class with jQuery is pretty much not possible, so I'm guessing you would have to create an actual element instead of the pseudo class.

Answer (score 1):

Every CSS selector is not allowed in jQuery. Only a little bit of them are allowed, for example `.` class selector, `#` id selector, `:first-child` child selector.

Other than that, jQuery has its own methods of selecting elements of type. Like `:checkbox` (https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

Other CSS selectors are not valid in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

So you can't do exactly what you want, but you can show/hide your `:before` in CSS based on a class, and then add that class later on to show it. Example:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cNNU/)**

**HTML**

```
<p>Example</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p.toggled:before {
    content: "show-me";
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("p").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
});
```